# IC: I2C communications over a DC bus

Tags: dc, i2c, uart, bus

I have been looking everywhere for a method to use i2c over a 12-48V DC power bus.

Are their any current IC solutions that I could check out?

If not where would be a good place to start on such a design? I know I could put an rf choke in before I inject the comm's and after I take it out but that really only works with >1MHz.

Comment: Why do you want to communicate over a DC bus, instead of adding a separate communication bus?

Comment: I have a specific task and I just want to know if you can do i2c over DC. If it needs >$8 in parts it would be cheaper to run more wires but things like water tight connectors and high temperature wiring is not cheap.

Comment: You may need a signalling scheme without a dc component, or to modulate a carrier.  Think of it as building a radio modem.

Comment: @uMinded  Perhaps, you could look into chipsets for powerline modems.  Can't think of other commodity things (around $8), which could fit your requirement.

Comment: There's Dallas Semiconductor's 1-wire system, which is worth looking at. Or the various model train control systems ("DCC").

Comment: The host system only has i2c and spi communication interfaces.

Comment: 1-wire systems do not need a "communication interface", they need a single GPIO, and that's it. Any MCU can do 1-wire communication.

Comment: I know it's a really old question, but have you figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress seem to have a suitable I2C power-line modem device ([CY8CPLC10](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=26408)) and provides reference designs for 12 to 24V DC power-lines which you may be able to modify for 48V.

Comment: I took a quick look at the datasheet for this chip and I don't think this is what the OP is looking for. This chip uses I2C for access to the chip's memory. It is NOT a transparent I2C bridge! It could be used to implement communications using I2C but would require an I2C master (processor) at each end to read/write packets from/to the chip's memory.

Comment: Yea adding a proc to each end would increase the price quite a bit. Not to mention those chips are $10 a piece...

Comment: Somebody had downvoted this.   @uMinded , was it you?

Comment: @Nick: Not me. Do you know of any discrete component powerline comms projects?